# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error on android webview using XAMPP on windows

Tags: apache, android-studio, webview

The Webview is trying to open a page who do few constant requests, the problem is happening only on the test server, if i use production on the shared hosting works. Basicly the webview is returning net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

I already change all this guys to high values:

```
memory_limit = 1024M

max_input_vars = 2000

upload_max_filesize = 300M

post_max_size = 300M

max_execution_time = 990

SSLRenegBufferSize 10486000
```

Did not solve, the problem is happening even when I try to open a small json of like 30 lines. The weird part sometimes happens some not, and on the computer browser most of the times works. Maybe is something with the php, atualy i'm using a GET parameter to refresh the cache on the urls like study.json?v=randomNumber()

Some times happen with the index page to.

The apache error log does not show anything.

I'm little desperate because i'm more than 8 hours on this problem already. 
Another thing i did was fix the certificate of the ssl, but still giving this error:

https://i.ibb.co/25wr7rz/errors.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the save battery mode being active in you Android device on battery settings.

Try to disable the save battery mode and retry.